# I am updating the contents of the div but how can I keep them there until the fresh data are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my jQuery below reloads the reloadhomeposts.php file. My question is how can I keep the reloaded data and not be disappeared until the fresh loaded content will be shown?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function () {
    function loadReservationDetails() {
        $('#reservationdetails')
            .empty()
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('wp-content/themes/theme/reloadhomeposts.php', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                setTimeout(loadReservationDetails, 20000);
        });
    }

    loadReservationDetails();
});
</script>
```

Comment: This question needs a rephrasing. What do you mean my keep the reloaded data not to be desappeared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just don't call the `.empty()` method like so:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function () {
    function loadReservationDetails() {
        $('#reservationdetails')
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('wp-content/themes/theme/reloadhomeposts.php', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                setTimeout(loadReservationDetails, 20000);
        });
    }

    loadReservationDetails();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the call to `empty` that is removing the current content before the request is sent. Just remve that call, and the current content remains until it's replaced by the new data in the response:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
  function loadReservationDetails() {
    $('#reservationdetails')
      .addClass('loading')
      .load('wp-content/themes/theme/reloadhomeposts.php', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('loading');
        window.setTimeout(loadReservationDetails, 20000);
    });
  }

  loadReservationDetails();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load data to another div, and then swap it with your first div.

Answer (score 0):

No need to call `.empty()` as old data will automatically be replaced with the new one. Like:

```
$(function () {
    function loadReservationDetails() {
        $('#reservationdetails')
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('wp-content/themes/theme/reloadhomeposts.php', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                setTimeout(loadReservationDetails, 20000);
        });
    }

    loadReservationDetails();
});
```